# conditional formatting apparently not working as expected in google spreadsheet. did the opposite of evaluating less than or equal to

Tags: google-sheets

In the attached screenshot, you can clearly see that the value in the specified cell is obviously greater than the value in cell O1

and that my conditional formatting states that value is *less than or equal to* O1

### Expected result

The fill is NOT green for O9 ( 17.32 ) which is definitely greater than O1 ( 15.80 ).

### Actual result

The fill is green for O9 despite the values and the rule.

[image]

I have no idea why this is the case, and I have already sent a help request to Google with a screenshot 1 week ago. The issue persists.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either you use a custom formula in your conditional formatting.

```
=($O9<$O$1)*($O9<>"")
```

or you use less than `=$O$1`

Note the `=` is important!

Comment: The custom formulas means: if the value entered in column O (from row 9 onwards --> note that only the column has the anchor symbol ($), making only the column 'absolute' while the row stays 'relative') is smaller than O1 AND that cell is not empty, apply the conditional formatting. If we leave out the last part empty cells would have the conditional formatting too.

Comment: if u look at my screenshot, u can see clearly that O9 is not empty. and yet the fill is green despite the fact that the value of O9 is greater than O1. So I am still not sure why your conditional formatting custom formula works and not the standard less than

Comment: the formula references the cell. I'm not sure your rule references the contents of the cell O1. To test, replace 'O1' with the actual value in O1, 15.80

Comment: Like the way you reference a cell in a spreadsheet: =O1 (not just O1).

Comment: that's the answer i was looking for!